# Can I use the embedded ST-Link in the STM32 DIscovery as UART communication with a terminal?

Tags: stm32

I have an STM32 discovery board and I want print information into a terminal in my pc, but I don't want to use an other UART cable, I want to use the same ST-Link cable ?

Can I do that ?

Comment: It depends which STM32 Discovery board you have and whether the embedded ST-Link supports the feature and if the UART pins are actually connected to the target MCU. You don't provide info, but it reads in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use integrated ST-Link of the STM32 Discovery as a UART bridge, however, it will need a little bit of research on your side.

You will need a board schematic of your discovery (available on ST website) and, if available, other supporting documentation for it (also on ST). In the board schematic you can find ST-Link page and see the TX/RX pins of ST-Link. They can have different line names, but there is "TX" or "RX" in their names. Find the same lines on the MCU page. Sometimes there are no lines with the same names on MCU side and you actually need to solder wires from these TX/RX pins of ST-Link to some MCU pins if there is no connection on Disco PCB. It depends entirely on the model of the disco.

When you figured out the pins of MCU to which ST-Link UART is connected or can be connected, you will have to find in the datasheet of MCU what USART interface they are on - USART1 or 2 or 3 or whatever (or if there is no connection you go the other way around - you find in the datasheet the pins of MCU you can connect ST-Link's TX & RX to)

Sometimes you can skip most of these steps and find something about it right in Disco-specific documentation, so check that thing first. No guarantee, but if there is something, it will save you a lot of reading.

STM32 is all about reading docs. You will have to get used to it.